# CoreData create relationship when binding to NSArrayController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, xcode4, uibuilder

## The setup:

### CoreData Model

- Product Entity

  - **Attribute** "name"
  - **Relationship** "common" <---> CommonData
- CommonData Entity

  - **Attribute** "product_id"
  - **Relationship** "product" <---> Product Entity

### View Setup:

- I have a NSTableView to display the product entities and it is bound to an NSArrayController
- There are two buttons "+" and "-" bound to `add:` and `remove:` to the respective actions of the NSArrayController.
- There is an NSObject controller bound to the `selection.common` content object, with a NSTextView bound to the NSObjectController.

In the Cocoa documentation, it states that the Releationship Entity is not automatically create when, in this case, the product entity is allocated. I can see this behavior when I click the "+" button. The product is added to the NSTableView, but the NSTextView displays "No Context". And, if I create the *product* and *common* entities in code, I can see NSTextView display the *product_id* correctly.

I would like to be able to keep the buttons bound to the NSArrayController.

## The Question:

- Is there any way to detect that the new product entity has been created?
- What is the best way to add the relationship entity when the new product entity is created via a button action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case I don't think merely doing `add:` will suffice. You should link your Add button to a new action method, and in this action method you should create a Product object and a CommonData object, and then set the "common" of the former to be the latter. At least that's what I would have done.

In any case, I think that doing some "detection" of a new CommonData object would be way of an overkill in this case.